# How read table with non utf-8 encoding in aws gllue?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, character-encoding, aws-glue

Here is a code snipped for reading csv files (scala):

```
val input = glueContext
  .getCatalogSource(database = "my_database", tableName = "my_table")
  .getDynamicFrame()
```

Which failed with unclear error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FatalException: Unable to parse file: my_file_20170101.csv.gz
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.JacksonReader.hasNextFailSafe(JacksonReader.scala:91)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.JacksonReader.hasNext(JacksonReader.scala:36)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.hadoop.TapeHadoopRecordReader.nextKeyValue(TapeHadoopRecordReader.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:199)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The code works for other scv files, but this one has `ANSI` encoding. Is there a way to tell glue (or may to spark internals) to read file with different encoding?

Comment: I'm not an expert on AWS Glue. In Spark you'd define the format as an option. It looks like the object returned by `getCatalogSource` has a method `withFormat` that perhaps can be of help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-datasource-trait.html

Comment: i ran into the same issue with ISO-8859-1. had to run iconv to convert to UTF-8, unfortunately. looks like Glue doesn't support different encodings just yet. as stefanobaghino said you could just write your ETL script with Spark DF's for now.

Answer (score 3):

Can use the underlying spark functionality to import a spark df from a non UTF-8 file (I used python as below):

```
# imports
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

...

# set contexts
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

....

# import file
df = glueContext.read.load(my_file,
                           format="csv",
                           sep="|",
                           header="true",
                           encoding='my_encoding')
```